# Select only 5 child-values from the same column, multiple parent-values in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Can I get some help with this?

Database: CompanyXYZ

Table: mkt_product

Category ID is the parent value and Product ID is the child value

**I have those columns, in the same table:**

| Product ID | Category ID | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | cat1 | Washing machine |
| 002 | cat1 | Refrigerator |
| 003 | cat1 | Oven |
| 004 | cat1 | Built in Oven |
| 005 | cat1 | Microwave |
| 006 | cat1 | Vacuum cleaner |
| 007 | cat1 | Hob |
| 008 | cat2 | Potato |
| 009 | cat2 | Carrot |
| 010 | cat2 | Onion |
| 011 | cat2 | Garlic |
| 012 | cat2 | Tomato |
| 013 | cat2 | Cucumber |
| 014 | cat2 | Lettuce |

**The result I want:**

| Product ID | Category ID | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | cat1 | Washing machine |
| 002 | cat1 | Refrigerator |
| 003 | cat1 | Oven |
| 004 | cat1 | Built in Oven |
| 005 | cat1 | Microwave |
| 008 | cat2 | Potato |
| 009 | cat2 | Carrot |
| 010 | cat2 | Onion |
| 011 | cat2 | Garlic |
| 012 | cat2 | Tomato |

In the end, it doesn't matter if I get the top 5 results from each category, but I want only 5 results from each category. It's like a 'limit 5' for each category but in the same output, only one query.
I tried with 'limit' and 'having count' but I don't get what i want.

Thank you!

Comment: You can check this [window-functions-usage](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html)

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment,you can using [**window-functions-usage**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) to do it

Schema code:

```
create table mkt_product(
  product_id varchar(100),
 category_id varchar(100),
 product varchar(100)
);

insert into mkt_product(product_id,category_id,product) 
values
('001','cat1','Washing machine'),
('002','cat1','Refrigerator'),
('003','cat1','Oven'),
('004','cat1','Built in Oven'),
('005','cat1','Microwave'),
('006','cat1','Vacuum cleaner'),
('007','cat1','Hob'),
('008','cat2','Potato'),
('009','cat2','Carrot'),
('010','cat2','Onion'),
('011','cat2','Garlic'),
('012','cat2','Tomato'),
('013','cat2','Cucumber'),
('014','cat2','Lettuce');
```

Query sql:

```
  SELECT t1.*
  FROM mkt_product t1
  JOIN
  (
     SELECT product_id,category_id,product,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY category_id ORDER BY product_id) as rn  
     FROM mkt_product
   ) t2 ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id 
     AND t1.category_id=t2.category_id AND t1.product=t2.product
  WHERE rn<=5
```

Note: `t1.product_id = t2.product_id AND t1.category_id=t2.category_id AND t1.product=t2.product` is very ugly,if your table have primary key such as id,it would be more simple

[**DB Fiddle Demo**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/muXvHEt3FGH78SjcC3oseq/1)

Comment: Thank you for all those info. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to use all those functions but I will try with another user.